# gspread to google sheets, text wrapping help need

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to import a CSV to Google sheets (this is working correctly)

After this I want all the cells in the sheet to wrap the text.

I have tried it in multiple different ways, however, I always have some kind of error.

This is the code I am running:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='C:/pathtomyfile.json')
sh = gc.open("gsheetsname")
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

content = open('csvfilename.csv', 'rb').read()
gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)

worksheet.format("A:E", {"wrapStrategy": "WRAP"})
```

The errors I seem to be getting is something along the lines of:
gspread.exceptions.APIError:

```
 {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].repeatCell: No grid with id: 828077185', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

I tried renaming the google sheet, renaming the worksheet, tried different modules, also tried importing gspread-formatting, however nothing seems to really be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)` might be the reason of your issue. When `gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)` is run, it seems that new sheet is inserted by including the values of `content` and the existing sheets are deleted. By this, `worksheet` of `worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)` is removed. I thought that this is the reason of your issue of `No grid with id: 828077185`.

In order to avoid this, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='C:/pathtomyfile.json')
sh = gc.open("gsheetsname")
content = open('csvfilename.csv', 'rb').read()
gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)

worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0) # I moved this line here.

worksheet.format("A:E", {"wrapStrategy": "WRAP"})
```

#### Reference:

- [import_csv(file_id, data)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=import_csv#gspread.Client.import_csv)

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue, awesome, thanks!
While I have this thread open, Do you by chance know how to make the Width of Colum A and Colum C double the size? And Filter Colum E from Z-A? I took a look at Google's API list but couldn't find these

Comment: @RH You can modify column widths via the gspread-formatting package. See https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/ for examples.